# How to modify the prompt words of Mathematica's artificial intelligence notebook?

Tags: chatai

Since Mathematica version 13 started supporting chatgpt, there's been a problem. I feel that its prompt words are not very good. I want to replace them with my own prompt words. How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: You can use a library of existing prompts (by clicking on the prompt icon) or define your own prompts, as discussed here.  https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2023/06/prompts-for-work-play-launching-the-wolfram-prompt-repository/

Comment: @JoshuaSchrier Thank you for your suggestion